# Redirect to specific url instead of 404 in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Instead of doing a raise Http404 in the following code, I would like to send the user to a specific URL ('/risking/notyours/').  I have tried to use `HttpResponseRedirect` and `reverse`, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Suggestions?

Code:

```
class ProspectDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Prospect
    template_name = 'risking/prospect_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """ Hook to ensure object is owned by request.user. """
        obj = super(ProspectDelete, self).get_object()
        if not obj.owner == self.request.user:
            raise Http404 ###This is what I need to change###
        return obj
```

Comment: Note that it might be a bad idea to return a "This object is not yours" message, because you are revealing the existence of the object to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_object` method should return a model instance. You can't return a redirect response from there.

One option would be to raise a custom exception and catch it in the `dispatch` method.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class WrongOwner(Exception):
    pass

class ProspectDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    ...   

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(ProspectDelete, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except WrongOwner:
            return redirect('/risking/notyours/')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """ Hook to ensure object is owned by request.user. """
        obj = super(ProspectDelete, self).get_object()
        if not obj.owner == self.request.user:
            raise WrongOwner
        return obj
```